# Best way to group multiple libraries & lists, so that related data are close to each other

Tags: list, libraries

I'm working in SharePoint Online and really trying to cut down on have multiple folders all over the place.  I am converting the data into libraries and lists.  Is there a suitable approach I can take form the UI that allows me to "group" multiple libraries **or** lists together, *that relate to each other*?

Allow me to paint the picture...

- I have 50 lists in my SharePoint site.
- 7 out of these 50 lists relate to each other.
- I hire a new staff member who is responsible for finding and knowing that these 7 lists relate to each other.

What can I do in this site to make that process work for this new staff member?

- i.e. Can these 7 lists be grouped somehow?
- i.e. Can these 7 lists be listed onto a custom SharePoint page somehow?
- i.e. Can these 7 lists have connected metadata, which can be searched on?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to group lists/libraries is using sites. If the seven lists are associated with each other, and not the other 43, then they should be in their own site. Sites also allow you to easily configure permissions, and then be default all lists/libraries in the site will have the same permissions.

If this really can't be done, then perhaps create a page that lists the seven list and provide links to each list.